# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timestamp'

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to select only those rows that have a timestamp that belongs to last 36 hours. My PySpark DataFrame `df` has a column `unix_timestamp` that is a timestamp in seconds.
This is my current code, but it fails with the error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`. I tried to change it to `unix_timestamp`, but it fails all the time.

```
import datetime
hours_36 = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours = 36)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", df.unix_timestamp.cast("timestamp")).filter(df.timestamp > hours_36)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time stamp column doesn't exist yet when you try to refer to it; You can either use `pyspark.sql.functions.col` to refer to it in a dynamic way without specifying which data frame object the column belongs to as:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", df.unix_timestamp.cast("timestamp")).filter(F.col("unix_timestamp") > hours_36)
```

Or without creating the intermediate column:

```
df.filter(df.unix_timestamp.cast("timestamp") > hours_36)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does the command `df.unix_timestamp.cast("timestamp")` exactly do? I am a bit confused with it. It casts `unix_timestamp` to timestamp, but it's already a timestamp.

Comment: Yes it casts column `unix_timestamp` to timestamp, if it's already a timestamp, then there is no need for that. What does `df.printSchema()` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

The API Doc tells me that you can also use a String notation for filtering:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("unix_timestamp", df.unix_timestamp.cast("timestamp"))
    .filter("unix_timestamp > %s" % hours_36)
```

Maybe its not so effienc though